# Pi B, Raspbian Jessie. Watchdog doesn't start at boot

Tags: raspbian-jessie, watchdog

After upgrading to Jessie, watchdog doesn't start at boot anymore. Starting it manually using "sudo service watchdog start" does work.
I tried:

- purging and reinstalling watchdog
- update-rc.d

I checked

- syslog with systemd verbosity on debug, no results. Other than the watchdog device nothing is mentioned.
- found this bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768168 but I have version 5.14-3 so this shouldn't apply.

What else can I try?

Comment: You should include the exact `update-rc.d` command you used, what your default runlevel is (`runlevel` will tell you), and then what priority `update-rc.d` assigned in the init directory for that service (those are `/etc/rcN.d`, where `N` is the runlevel; the priority is the number prefixed to the service file link).   You might also want to try `systemctl list-units | grep -i watchdog` to see if you can use systemd directly for this instead.

Comment: My runlevel is 5, the priority also is 5. I used `sudo update-rc.d watchdog defaults` and `sudo update-rc.d watchdog enable`. The output of `systemctl` is empty.

Comment: You might want to about this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Include all the details you have here, including the fact that `update-rc.d` did work because `/etc/rc5.d/S05watchdog` exists (that's all `update-rc.d` does, so that is not the problem, presuming that is the name of the link you found).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218796/watchdog-daemon-doesnt-start-at-boot/218800#218800) Ineb answered:

> Open
>
> ```
> /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service and add 
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```
>
> Systemd needs the [Install]-Section for a Unit to know how it should
>   enable/disable the Unit.

After that calling `systemctl enable watchdog` worked.

Comment: `[Install]` section is there, but service doesn't start automatically. What to do?

Comment: Normally `systemctl enable watchdog` should do this. Is there any output when you try to enable the service?

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable watchdog`
`Synchronizing state for watchdog.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...`
`Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d watchdog defaults`
`Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d watchdog enable`. And `/etc/init.d/watchdog status` shows `active (running)` when started manually. Then I make `reboot` and ... Oh gosh! It is active! Thank you, but I don't know why it worked this time.